# Can't remove the terminal profiles panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since recently, VS Code insiders terminal pane started to display a profiles sub-panel. How can I remove/hide it?
[image]

VS Code version: 1.56.0-insider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121711) (outdated) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122708), this setting is new and the corresponding value in the settings is:

*Outdated:*

```
"terminal.integrated.showTabs": false
```

**Now:**

```
"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": false
```